# [OAuth2 authorization server]refresh token's expire time need different with access token?

Tags: asp.net, oauth, oauth-2.0, owin

I'm learning OAuth2 via this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server), then I found refresh token's expire time is the same as access token, is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**That's true: refresh tokens issued by the OAuth2 authorization server built in OWIN/Katana always have the same expiration date as access tokens** ; even if you specify an explicit `ExpiresUtc` property in `AuthenticationProperties` when you call `IOwinContext.Authentication.SignIn(identity, properties)`

https://github.com/yreynhout/katana-clone/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth/OAuthAuthorizationServerHandler.cs#L333

That's not really convenient for the reasons @Hans mentioned but you can override this behavior in `AuthenticationTokenProvider.CreateAsync` (the class you use for `OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions.RefreshTokenProvider`):

Simply set `context.Ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc` with the expiration date of your choice, and the refresh token will be issued with a different expiration date:

```
public class RefreshTokenProvider : AuthenticationTokenProvider {
    public override void Create(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context) {
        context.Ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = // set the appropriate expiration date.

        context.SetToken(context.SerializeTicket());
    }
}
```

---

You can also take a look at `AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server`, a fork of the OAuth2 authorization server offered by OWIN/Katana that has a native `RefreshTokenLifetime`: https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server/tree/dev

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectServer(options => {
    // Essential properties omitted for brevity.
    // See https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server/tree/dev/samples/Mvc for more information.

    // RefreshTokenLifetime allows you to define a lifetime specific to refresh tokens,
    // which is totally independent of the lifetime used for access tokens.
    options.RefreshTokenLifetime = TimeSpan.FromDays(14);
});
```

Don't hesitate to ping me if you need help.

Comment: I got it, thank you very much. But why katana setting them into the same?

Answer (score 0):

In general that does not make much sense: the `refresh_token` exists to allow the Client to get a new `access_token` when the current one expires. If the `refresh_token` has also expired by then, there's nothing that a Client can do with it so it is useless.

There's one (more or less) edge case in which this is useful though: when the Resource Server actively rejects the `access_token` before it expires, the Client can now go back to the Authorization Server to get a new `access_token`.